# Problems with pyimagej module imagej not found

Tags: python, pycharm, jython, pyimagej

I installed pyimagej:

```
pip3 install pyimagej
```

After installing it, I created a conda imagej environment.

```
conda create -n imagej -c conda-forge openjdk=8 pyimagej
```

In my pycharm IDE I set the right python interpreter in my imagej environment.

My script starts with:

```
import imagej
ij = imagej.init()

from ij import IJ
```

It gives me the error

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ij'

I don't understand, as the python interpreter definitely has the package pyimage in it.

Thanks for help!

The same issue was already posted here:
https://forum.image.sc/t/cannot-find-imagej-module-after-installing-pyimagej-with-conda/23190/5
but there was no solution to it.

Comment: You can always use the imagej script editor to run jython code. I would prefer the PyCharm IDE though, as debugging is easier.

Comment: You have installed pyimagej in a Python 3 environment. That does not make pyimagej available in Jython (whose latest version is 2.7.2).

Comment: Oh my god, thank you!!!!